# Get multiple dataTables from a sqlDataAdapter

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm not even sure what I'm asking is even possible, but here goes:

Is there a way to loop through a sqlDataAdapter to find multiple tables?

Currently I have a module that you pass in an object and it automatically fills the parameters of a stored procedure with the values of the object. It works great, except when the stored procedure returns more than one table, it only returns the first one.

Here is what I tried to get to that second table:

```
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim table As New DataTable
Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader
While reader.IsClosed = False
        reader.Read()
        Try
            table.Load(reader)
            If Not ds.Tables.Contains(table.TableName) Then
                ds.Tables.Add(table)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End While
```

Any help / ideas would be helpfull!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want a SqlDataReader. You want a SqlCommand, A SqlDataAdapter, and rigorous use of the `using` statement:

```
Using connection As New SqlConnection(myConnectionString)
    connection.Open()
    Using command As New SqlCommand(connection)
        command.CommandText = "myStoredProcedure"
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        Using adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command)
            Dim dataset As new DataSet()
            adapter.Fill(dataSet)
            For Each table As DataTable In dataset.Tables
                ' Do something spectacular
            Next
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: The Above answer is correct, but as an Extra bit of information if you know what your Table Structure output are going to be i would actually create a Strongly Typed DataSet, so that when you are doing the Loop of dataset.Table you can then refer to the Table by the name you give the table in your Strongly Types Dataset. +1 for @Mike Hofer.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you. I can't believe I never thought of using a sqlDataAdapter, you just made me save a lot of time.

Comment: Unfortunately the table changes depending on the current month, so I can't predict what it will look like, but thanks for the additionnal info Robbie